# Git double repository management

Tags: git, repository, mirroring

as in the title I need to know ho to manage a double repository.
We are two different team and we have two different (there are some reason for that) repository.
My team has setted in the project the two different url, so when I push -all we will have both repo updated.

The second team only push to 1 of the repo(Bitbucket) they don't have visibility of the other.
Today something strange happened:
Second team push something on the repository(Bitbucket), while my team push other stuff on both repository (Bitbucket, GitLab).

My team so work in gitLab and push to the two repo.
When the my team pushed some stuff didnt'see any alert.
So we were able to push something without pull from bitbucket, but all the commit that second team pushed have disappeared.
We only have our commit of GitLab.

How we can handle that?

Comment: My guess is that someone actually did a force push. You shouldn't be able to remove commits without doing this. So either this is a bug in some of the involved pieces of software, or one of you did a force push, maybe without realizing. Did you use a GUI tool to push? Does it remember the last setting you used?

Comment: You're looking for `--force-with-lease` that eliminates the [toctou](https://www.google.com/search?q=toctou) window when checking whether you've seen the current tip before allowing an overwrite.

Comment: No force push, and we have used a GUI tool : FORK.